# Function start() not running in text-adventure-game

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Im currently trying to program a little text adventure.
*My Problem is that, while the button that's supposed to start the game is working to some extend, is does not trigger the start function (start()).*
The code is split between an index-site (index.html) a script-site (script.js) and a library (qalib.js). The start function which is supposed to be triggered on the qalib.js, is defined on the script.js and I think it might have something to do with that. I tried to connect the two sites with an include function I found on some website, but that didn't work. Do you have an idea why the game isn't running and what I could do to change that? Thank you for your help in advance!

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title>A Text Adventure</title>
    
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
                
        <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
            <div id="inout" hidden>
                <div id="output"></div>
                <div id="input">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label id="questiontext" for="answer">Antwort:</label>
                                <input id="answertext" name="answer" type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <button id="answerbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Antworten</button> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>   
        
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        <script src="qalib.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        
        
    </body>

</html>
```

script.js:

```
$(function() {
  zeigeStartBild("Herzlich Willkommen! <br> Es folgt ein kleines Text-Adventure.","Starte das Spiel!");
});

function start() {
    output("Hallo");
    input("Wie heißt du?", antwortName);
}

var name;
function antwortName(antwort) {
    name = antwort;
        if (antwort == "Herr Schiller") {
            output("Na dann wissen sie meine Arbeit hoffentlich zu schätzen!");
            hsnachricht()
        }
        else {
            output("Herzlich Willkommen " + name + "!");
            frage2();
        }
}

function frage2() {
    output("Jedenfalls " + name + ", schön das du hier vorbei schaust! Sag mal, hast du Lust auf ein Rätsel? Falls du richtig rätst gibt es auch eine Überraschung!");  
    input("'Ja.' oder 'Nein.'?", antwortJaNein);
}

function antwortJaNein(antwort) {
        if (antwort == "Ja.") {
            output("Sehr gut! Das freut mich!");
            frage3();
        }
        else if (antwort == "Nein.") {
            output("Na gut, dann eben nicht!");
            badend()
        }
        else {
            output("Das nehme ich als ein Ja!");
            frage3();
        }
}

function frage3() {
    output("Also" + name + ", dann mach dich mal bereit.. Hier das Rästel:");  
    input("Welches Wort im Wörterbuch aus dem Jahr 2019 wird falsch geschrieben?", antwortRaetsel);
}

function antwortRaestel(antwort) {
        if (antwort == "Das Wort 'falsch'.") {
            output("Richtig! Gut gemacht!");
            goodend()
        }
        else if (antwort == "falsch") {
            output("Genau richtig! Tolle Arbeit!");
            goodend()
        }
        else {
            output("Nope, aber das war ein netter Versuch.");
            badend()
        }
}


function badend() {
    output("Aber sag nicht, ich hätte dich nicht gefragt, hehe! Bye!");  
    end()
}


function hsnachricht() {
    output("Der Code basiert auf dem von diesem Video: ' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40poeMYP0n8 '." <br> 
    "Haben Sie Spaß mit den Spiel!");  
    frage2()
}

function goodend() {
    output("Du bist ja ziemlich gut im Rätseln! Das sollten wir öfters machen!"<br>
    "Hier ist erstmal deine Überraschung!" <br>
    "Auf dieser Website kannst du mein Erlebnis an diesem Projekt zu arbeiten nacherleben: ' https://www.hackertyper.com/ '."<br>
    "See you later alligator!");  
    end2()

function end() {
            alert("Du hast das Spiel 'See You Later Alligator' abgeschlossen.");
        }

function end2() {
            alert("Du hast das Spiel 'See You Later Alligator' erfolgreich abgeschlossen.");
        }
```

qalib.js:

```
function zeigeStartBild(msgtext, btntext) {
    $("#main").append(
        "<div id=\"startbild\" class=\"jumbotron\">\
            <h1>Hallo!</h1>\
            <p>" + msgtext +"</p>\
            <p><button class=\"btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg\" id=\"start_btn\">" + btntext + "</button></p>\
        </div>");
        
    $("#start_btn").click(function() {
        $("#startbild").hide();
        $("#inout").show();
        
        start();
    });
}


function clear() {
    $("#output").empty();
}

function output(msg) {
    $("#output").append("<div class=\"alert alert-info\">" + msg + "</div>");
}

function answeroutput(msg) {
    $("#output").append("<div class=\"alert alert-success text-right\">" + msg + "</div>");
}

var currentanswer = "";
var answered = false;
$("#answerbtn").click(function() {
    currentanswer = $("#answertext").val();
    $("#input").hide();
    $("#answertext").val("");
    answered = true;
    answeroutput(currentanswer);
});

var answercallback = undefined;
function input(question, callback) {
    $("#questiontext").text(question);
    $("#input").show();
    answered = false;
    answercallback = callback;
    waitForInput()
    
}

function waitForInput(callback) {
    if (!answered) {
        setTimeout(waitForInput, 500);
        }
    else {
        answercallback(currentanswer)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that you have the click event

```
$("#start_btn").click(function() {
  $("#startbild").hide();
  $("#inout").show();
    
  start();
});
```

Inside of another function.

So it should be a quick fix by moving that whole block out of the function its currently in.

For example:

```
function zeigeStartBild(msgtext, btntext) {
$("#main").append(
    "<div id=\"startbild\" class=\"jumbotron\">\
        <h1>Hallo!</h1>\
        <p>" + msgtext +"</p>\
        <p><button class=\"btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg\" id=\"start_btn\">" + btntext + "</button></p>\
    </div>");
}

$("#start_btn").click(function() {
    $("#startbild").hide();
    $("#inout").show();
    
    start();
});
```

Comment: @Jan explained to me, that the problem was caused by the bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js. Removing them solved the problem with the button (Thank you so much for your help btw! I wouldn't have noticed the problem without you Jan!), but it also removed the design/layout of the site (e.g. it changed the design of a nav bar I  removed from the code to keep it short for this question). Which is a bummer! Is there a way, to work around that?

Comment: I think you could put your "games" html in its own Iframe and then add it to your "main page" where you have your navbar and bootstrap css and the game's layout then shouldn't be affected by bootstrap (Haven't tested that but probably would work)